# App\Entity\PlaylistForCompany object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

For several days now I have been stuck on this error:
[error : App\Entity\PlaylistForCompany object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXD6V.png)

Here is the code for the controller (admin_company_parcours):

[controller : admin_company_parcours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bte8x.png)

If you have any ideas on what this might look like knowing that I've tried a few tricks already without success.
Thanking you, cordially

Comment: [Avoid using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in your questions.  Copy/paste the relevant information and format as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony succesfully resolves your `Company` entity using the `id` parameter in your route. However, Symfony can't automatically resolve more than one entity unless your route contains more parameters. Therefore, `$playlistForCompany` can't be resolved as Symfony does not know which entity to query.

As you are not persisting any new value in your code, I assume that `$playlistForCompany` must be an existing entity, somewhat related to `$company`.

1. If your `Company` entity has an association field to the `PlaylistForCompany` entity, you can retrieve it using the corresponding `getter`.
2. If not, you will have to use your `PlaylistRepository` and manually retrieve it.

```php
public function parcours(Company $company, Request $request): Response
{
  $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $playlistRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(PlaylistForCompany::class);

  $playlistForCompany = $company->getPlaylistForCompany();  // 1. with getter
  $playlistForCompany = $playlistRepository->find(...);     // 2. with repository

  $form = $this->createForm(PlaylistForCompanyType::class, $playlistForCompany);
  $form->handleRequest($request);
  ...
}
```

Comment: @clementLehuede Please accept my answer to flag your question as answered if it solved your problem, thank you :)